# asp.net mvc Records Based On other

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to create a listing view in which the record will be in this format(basically one record based on other, what approach i should follow) .

My table
Module1
Module1Feature
Module1Feaure2
Module1Feature3

Module2
Module2Feature
Module2Feature2
Module2Feature3

**Basically Please Notice that the child records are based on the parent.**

Comment: Are you using LinqToSQL as your backend?  I assumed in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using LinqToSQL as your backend, then you probably already have your foriegn key relationships setup (right?).  Which means that you should have a table with your modules and a table for your moduleFeatures with a FK back to table modules.

In your controller, you return all of your modules as such

```
Function Index() as actionresult
      return(repository.getModules())
End Function
```

Then in your View, you can do something like this

```
For each module in model
    Html.Encode(module.moduleName)
    For each feature in module
         Html.Encode(feature.featureName)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: No they are all in the same table named features , if something is module then ismodule is true for it otherwise false for features

Comment: I would rethink the database schema as any type of grouping, ordering, etc. will be much more easy if you create a one to many relationship as opposed to storing in a single table.  You will save yourself some heartache in the future.